# Seabron heatmap only annotating the first row

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have:

Python
3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0]

matplotlib
3.8.0

seaborn
0.12.2

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(np.random.rand(3, 3), annot=True)
```

The output on my system:

[image]

Only the first row gets annotated. I've tried various variations like just a script, in a notebook, saving to a file, but nothing makes a difference, always only the first row is annotated. What can the problem be?